# filter multiple objects and returns 'new field' in Serializer

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-rest-framework, django-views

[image: youtube capture]

Just like Youtube, I want to see **what categories my post(outfit) is in**.

My approach is...

1. Get whole list of categories belong to user
2. Get whole list of categories belong to user and the post
3. compare them and return JSON

While building a Seriailizer, I feel like I'm totally stock. So frustraing... :(

Please feel free to change my approach if you have any better idea.

Expected JSON outputis below

```
{
    ...
    "categories": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "asd"
        "added": True <- since the post is added to 'asd'
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "workout"
        "added": True
    }, 
    ...
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "bgm"
        "added": False <- since the post is not added to 'bgm'
    }, 
    ]
}
```

Here is views.py

```
class OutfitDetailView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Outfit.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OutfitDetailSerializer
    lookup_field = 'pk'
```

Here is serializers.py (this is a problem)

```
class OutfitDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     ...
   def get_categories(self, obj):
            # Right Here! Get whole categories associated with user
            all_categories = Category.objects.filter(owner=self.context['request'].user)
            # And the categories associated with user AND the post
            categories = obj.categories.filter(owner=self.context['request'].user)

            return CategorySerializer(categories, many=True).data

class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):    
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = (
            'id',
            'name',
            'added' <- here I want to add 'added' field but I don't know how.
        )
```

In case you need a model

```
class Outfit(models.Model):
    ...
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ...

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True)
    outfits = models.ManyToManyField(Outfit, related_name="categories", blank=True)
    main_img = models.ImageField(
                            upload_to=upload_location_category,
                            null=True,
                            blank=True)
    ...
```

Comment: added always `True`?

Comment: I just added more descriptions on JSON part. @BearBrown Thanks for pointing out

Comment: @BearBrown Let me know if anything is unclear

Comment: why in `posts = models.ManyToManyField(Outfit` you use `Outfit` does it typo?

Comment: That was typo. I just fixed it to 'Post'. Do you understand the problem?

Comment: i hope yes, wait e few minutes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154876/discussion-between-bear-brown-and-john-baek).

Comment: please, add real code of your models,  i will think more time for solution

Comment: Thanks I just did!

Comment: @BearBrown Any update? :) Maybe I should rewrite whole Model..

Comment: yes i do go to discus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand you correct, you can try:

```
class OutfitDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def get_categories(self, obj):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        categories = Category.objects.filter(owner=user)
        added = categories.extra(select={'added': '1'}).filter(outfits__pk=obj.pk)
        added = list(added.values('added', 'name', 'id'))
        added_f = categories.extra(select={'added': '0'}).exclude(outfits__pk=obj.pk)
        added_f = list(added_f.values('added', 'name', 'id'))
        categories = added + added_f
        return CategorySerializer(categories, many=True).data
```

Note in the `values` you need add all fields you need for the `CategorySerializer`

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    added = serializers.BooleanField()
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = (
            'id',
            'name',
            'added'
        )
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and try! I think you got the point but your provided code doesn't seem work because I only see {"name": "~~", "added": true} series outputs. I expect to see whole categories associated with user and the post.

Comment: Could you try one again..? I don't understand your code but I can see your logic which is very nice

Comment: Now the output is "categories": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Gym",
            "added": true
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "School",
            "added": true
        }
    ]

Comment: I expect to see {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Normal",
            "added": False
        } as well :) I think you got the point. Just to make sure

Comment: can you check the first `Category.objects.filter(owner=user)` is there `id=3` in my test data all work fine

Comment: here you go https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46340864/can-you-optimize-this-code-django-python